# LibraryLink`$LibraryError is "dlsym(..., WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper): symbol not found" after successful LibraryFunctionLoad

Tags: warning-messages, librarylink

On my computers (Mac OS X 10.10 and 10.11) Mathematica 10.3, running the first example in the documentation for [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) returns a working `LibraryFunction` without problems... apparently.

I recently discovered that, `` LibraryLink`$LibraryError `` actually reports an error, which I can't understand.

```
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo", "demo_I_I", {Integer}, Integer]
LibraryLink`$LibraryError
```

[image]

What is this `dlsym(..., WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper): symbol not found` issue?  And how do I address it?

Comment: nota bene:  ``LibraryLoad["demo"]; LibraryLink`$LibraryError`` returns `None`, so problem is confined to `LibraryFunctionLoad`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to be addressed on your side, it's technically a bug, but a harmless one.

Comment: @ilian Ok, good to know.  But it piqued my curiosity: what is `WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper`?  A search on Google yields 5 hits, one of which is [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/exceldna/9mDv26PPqBQ/GiGxe_iy5UEJ), which is a source file for what appears to be a correctly made Library.  Should I include in my source file a dummy `DLLEXPORT char * WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper(){}`?

Comment: Oh I see what's happening: `WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper` is a standard function that should be included in the source along with `WolframLibrary_initialize` and `WolframLibrary_getVersion`, and it returns a *Mathematica* expression (in `FullForm`) which is applied to the `LibraryFunction` object upon loading it.  Therefore, it seems most appropriate to add the line `DLLEXPORT char* WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper() {return "Function[Slot[1]]";}` to the source to maintain normal behavior, and *also* to resolve the error in ``LibraryLink`$LibraryError``.

Comment: @ilian I see, many thanks!  Can you answer this question, so I can mark it as such? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitioning my comment into an answer,

> The `WolframCompileLibrary_wrapper` function is not required to be present in a LibraryLink DLL.
>
> It is used by some DLLs in the case of generated code, i.e. `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to reconstruct the compiled function from the DLL.
>
> The error seen is simply the result of looking for it and is standard behavior for `dlsym` / `dlerror` if it happens to be absent, but that does not indicate a problem or interfere with normal operation – not so much a bug, but rather a potential source of confusion.